# Trying to hide the "undefined" from javascript map results

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I"m trying to hide the "undefined" from the results.
The first contact have a first name and family name but the second contact don't have a family name so it get's undefined.

Tried to use this filter

```
.filter(({ familyName }) => familyName !== undefined)
```

but it hides the entire row.

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts
        .map(({ givenName, familyName, organizationName, phoneNumbers }) => 
            `${givenName} ${familyName} ${organizationName} ${
                 phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
            }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = { success: true, contacts: [{ emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John", organizationName: "", familyName: "Appleseed" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John Appleseed", organizationName: "" }] };

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Lets give us an reaction on what did work the best for you, please.

Comment: All solutions working great but this is the best is think: || ""

Comment: What is the reason you choose this solution? I'm a bit curious ^^.

Comment: It was the fastes solution for me, less code the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `||` lets you quickly check if the value is `undefined or null`

```
.map(({ givenName, familyName, organizationName, phoneNumbers }) => 
  `${givenName} ${familyName || ''} ${phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an empty string as default `= ''` for the fields the might be `undefined`:

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts
        .map(({ givenName, familyName = '', organizationName = '', phoneNumbers }) => 
            `${givenName} ${familyName} ${organizationName} ${
                 phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
            }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = { success: true, contacts: [{ emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John", organizationName: "", familyName: "Appleseed" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John Appleseed", organizationName: "" }] };

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to omit the entire row when `familyName` is `undefined`, you can supply a *destructuring default* for it in your `map` call:

```
.map(({ givenName, familyName = "", organizationName, phoneNumbers }) => 
// --------------------------^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts
        .map(({ givenName, familyName = "", organizationName, phoneNumbers }) => 
            `${givenName} ${familyName} ${organizationName} ${
                 phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
            }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = { success: true, contacts: [{ emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John", organizationName: "", familyName: "Appleseed" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John Appleseed", organizationName: "" }] };

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

That deafult will get used if the object passed to the `map` callback has no `familyName` property, or it does but the value of the property is `undefined`. (Not any other falsy value, just `undefined` specifically.)

You can obviously do that for the other properties as well if you like, if they too may be missing or `undefined`.

If you weren't using destructuring, you might use the `||` trick:

```
${familyName || ""}
```

That will use `""` if `familyName` is any *falsy* value (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or of course, `false`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use default value, so in case of `undefined` the default value will be utilized.

```
.map(({ givenName='', familyName='',...})
                                  |______________ default value
```

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts
        .map(({ givenName='', familyName='', organizationName='', phoneNumbers='' }) => 
            `${givenName} ${familyName} ${organizationName} ${
                 phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
            }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = { success: true, contacts: [{ emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John", organizationName: "", familyName: "Appleseed" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "John Appleseed", organizationName: "" }] };

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```